# Android Eclipse Java comparing array contents with string. Not working?

Tags: java, string, compare

Hi I have an array that stores when radio buttons are checked so that when I load the radio settings again I can set the apporpriate one as checked.

My array is like this :

```
   |0          |1         |2
----------------------------------
0  |Option1    |data      |false
----------------------------------
1  |Option2    |data      |true
----------------------------------
2  |Option3    |data      |false
----------------------------------
3  |Option4    |data      |false
```

etc....

Now the index I am interested in is the true/false one as that tells me if that radio button should be checked.

I read these values from a database into the array.  That's all working fine and the data is in the array correctly.

For some reason when I do a comparison it does not match it up with what I can see is correct.

This is what I am doing in a loop...

```
String checked = myarray[i][2];

// This correctly outputs 'false', 'true', 'false' and 'false' as per the array above.            
Toast.makeText(DatabaseTestActivity.this, checked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// Now when it gets here it fails to trigger the match for 'true'.
if (checked == "true") {
     active = i;
     Toast.makeText(DatabaseTestActivity.this, "Found Check", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong ?  It's just a simple string compare, or so I thought ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.equals()` to compare strings.

```
if (checked.equals("true")) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks !  That was it - I am too used to PHP for my own good, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You should compare using [`String#equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) or [`String#equalsIgnoreCase`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29):

```
checked.equals( "true" )
```

`==` compares references, while `equals` compares the content of the string.